# How to create log of running application programmatically on android?

Tags: android

I am new to android, I want to create log of running application in my android app so when new application is lunched it log application name as well as date and time and send it to server when it requested.

I search about running application on android but most of them using `getRunningTasks()` which is deprecated in API 21.

Edit:

here is the code for reading cmdline file :

```
    private String procInfo(File cmdLine) {
    String name = null;
    String info = null;      
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(cmdLine));
        String line;
        name = br.readLine();           
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     Log.i("Content", file);        
    return name;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking because you want to track what a user is doing on their device or if you just want to track your device during development. If development I am not sure about sending to a server but you can do it with adb logcat. If you use LogRabbit it will display app name and timestamp right out of the box.

Comment: I want to track what a user doing on their device.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think I can help with this one. I can't think of any positive reasons to track a users activity outside of your own apps usage patterns.

Comment: This app is for school due to rule I want to check which application is run by student and create log of them. which contains application name and start and end time.

Comment: Are the devices root'd?

Comment: No, devices shouldn't be rooted.

Comment: Have you look at how this app works? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.agrvaibhav.AppUsageTracking&hl=en

Comment: Have a look at UsageStatsManager https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html

Answer (score 1):

I would probably start by looking in `/proc/[PID]/cmdline` or in `/proc/[PID]/status` and get the "Name" field.

As an educational exercise have a look at `ps` [code](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/toolbox/ps.c) in Android Core.

You can create a service that periodically monitors the list of PIDs and report the ones that come and go. To get the name look in one of the two files mentioned above.

Here is one example of how this might be done:

```
try {
    while (true) {
        File f = new File("/proc");
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        for (File inFile : files) {
            if (inFile.isDirectory()) {
                File cmdFile = new File(inFile, "status");
                if (cmdFile != null && cmdFile.isFile()) {
                    // Get the Name value from /proc/[PID]/status file
                    String cmdLine = procName(cmdFile);
                    if (cmdLine != null && cmdLine.length() > 0) {
                        Log.e("PS", new Date() + ", " + inFile.toString() + ", " + cmdLine);
                        // Keep Set of new PID or PID that disappear that will be sent to a server

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("PS", "Failed to process processes", e);
}
```

I've left it to you to figure out how to get the contents of the file and parse it.

The output of this example will be a comma delimited list of date, path and appname:

```
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1274, ng.indexservice 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1282, pp.galaxyfinder 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1298, ingbuddyservice 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1310, s.android.proxy 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1319, com.android.nfc 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1329, oviders.context 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1347, x.eventsmanager 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1362, .knox.seandroid 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1380, id.app.launcher 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1409, e.process.gapps 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1448, .service:remote 
Sun Aug 16 17:57:05 CDT 2015, /proc/1486, android.smspush
```

Comment: Thank, I will test it, should devices rooted for this?

Comment: I tested on JellyBean and not rooted and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I run it, but it return status as appname, also I get 'Server isn't responding do you want to close it on device'

Comment: You have to open the file status and parse out the field called "Name:"

Comment: Thanks, how can I list just application run by user and not running system file.

Comment: can I get time when user close it?

Comment: Yes, just use System.currentTimeMillis() when you don't see the app anymore.

Comment: how can I list just application run by user?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are several things you could do. Maybe the easiest is to just report delta to the server. So when your app starts grab all the PID and store those but don't report. When new apps come and go send those changes to the server. Or I think /proc/PID/cmdline is only set for apps that are started from UI. I am sure there are other ways but try these first. and filter out anything owned by root.

Comment: first I try to implement an [accesabilityservice](http://txt.do/aju6l) so that when user click, it notify me. but I couldn't make it work. then I try implement simple [service](http://txt.do/aju6h) and here is the [log](http://txt.do/aju6p). but I don't know how can I fillter anything own by root.  also I find [this](http://www.itcuties.com/android/how-to-get-running-process-list-and-traffic-statistics/) which I implement my [service](http://txt.do/aju6n) like it but it also list all process and I don't know how can I limit it to application run by user and also some of them aren't running!

Comment: I try to open /proc/pid/cmdline, but I get this error `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/cmdline: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` so I couldn't access this file

Comment: Was that only on some of them or was that for all of them?

Comment: its for the cmdline file, I could read status file. and didn't try others.

Comment: I meant for all PIDs. Do you get read failure for all cmdline files for all PID?

Comment: I make mistake its directory is /proc/cmdline and doesn't have PID.

Comment: I have access to /proc/[pid]/cmdline, how can I read this file?

Comment: It is just a plain text files. Many will be empty but I believe the ones launched by user will have the application name in it. Some you may not have read permission but the ones you are interested in should be fine. Do the same thing you did to read the status file. You can log data to http://lograbbit.com to make it easier to see what you are doing with ADB during your android development.

Comment: It contains null char as I understand, I would like to see its format. I use BufferedReader and read line by line. so I want to now what is the correct way to read this file?

Comment: As I mentioned above it is just a plain text file. Many will be empty but the ones you are looking for will contain text.

Comment: It contains something like this : `com.example.service������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������`, I would like to delete these � !

Comment: I think you have an error in your code. Can you put it somewhere I can have a look (like maybe GitHub)?

Comment: Instead of readLine read byte by byte until you get to 0x00 of -1.

Answer (score 0):

Try the Android API "[UsageStatsManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/UsageStatsManager.html)". You will need this permission: android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS

```
Calendar beginCal = Calendar.getInstance();
beginCal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
beginCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
beginCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2012);

Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
endCal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
endCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
endCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);

final List<UsageStats> queryUsageStats=usageStatsManager.queryUsageStats(UsageStatsManager.INTERVAL_YEARLY, beginCal.getTimeInMillis(), endCal.getTimeInMillis());
```

You can start it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is some sample code: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-AppUsageStatistics

-- Chris

http://lograbbit.com

Comment: I try to run sample code but I get this error on my eclipse when building the code, `Permission is only granted to system apps` for this permision `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS`